# align-item center on a custom radio button

Tags: html, css

Demo

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqwJWE

I did a custom radio button but the DOM structure make it hard to align middle for the custom checkbox, I need the label which has different rows to be at the right and the checkbox is center horizontally.

```
<div>
  <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"><p>Row one</p><p>Row two</p> </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with CSS Grid

Declare the grid as 2 rows by 2 columns (setting the first as min-content), align-items center, and make your :before element span 2 rows

```css
/* only demo styles */
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
}

.wrap{
/*prevents from occupying 100% width*/
  display:inline-block;
}

/* end only demo styles */

.checkbox-custom, .radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: grid;
    align-items:center;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label p, .radio-custom-label p{
  margin:0;
}

.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before, .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    /*tells the button to occupy both rows */
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    background: rebeccapurple;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
}


.checkbox-custom:focus + .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class='wrap'>
    <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"><p>Row one</p><p>Row two</p> </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: flexbox will do, is grid a bonus here?

Comment: @G-Cyr I achieve it using flexbox :P

Comment: @JennyTeng so do you know why it should do ? you know align-items + row is vertical alignement , justify-content would be for horizontal.?  input and label are children flex , not tthe pseudo nor the p ;) .Maybe you should show a screen of the desired effect. It will clarify the question and where you got confused

Comment: @JennyTeng really? I provided an answer using flexbox and you said it won't do. You cannot do this with flexbox because you're using the :before on the label to create the radio button. Since all 3 "elements" are siblings, you need grid to create the 2-dimensional layout. Flexbox would have worked if the "custom radio button" was a sibling of the label, not a sibling of the Ps

Comment: Any reason not to use grid? you can get it to work down to IE10.

Answer (score 1):

Just use flebox in your div

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}


p{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"><p>Row one</p><p>Row two</p> </label>
</div>
```

Comment: why it doesn't work here? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejXdZx Well you're not really answer the question, I mentioned custom checkbox

Comment: @JennyTeng doesn't work there because your custom checkbox is on the `label` instead of the `input`. Therefore, is a sibling of the `p`s, instead of a sibling of the `label` as I did in my stripped down example.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<p>` element then just add `<br/>` to it

```
 <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"><p>Row one</p><p>Row 
   two</p> </label>
```

into

```
<label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label">Row one<br/>Row 
       two </label>
```

then on your css :before add `float:left;`

```
.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
      float: left;
}
```

Check this Snippet

```css
/* only demo styles */

body {
  font-family: Raleway;
}

/* end only demo styles */

.checkbox-custom, .radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before, .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
      float: left;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    background: rebeccapurple;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
  float:left;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
      float: left;
}


.checkbox-custom:focus + .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}
```

```html
    <form>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" checked >
          <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label">Row one <br />Row two</label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the checkbox is not centered horizontally.